# Query schema of a table in one database from a stored proc in another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is there a way to query the schema of a table from a stored proc in another database without resorting to dynamic sql? The name of the database would be passed in as a parameter.

Comment: If you pass the name as parameter, you cannot do it without dynamic SQL.

Comment: That is a valid answer to my question "Is there a way..." No is one of the two answers I was expecting :)  Post as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the name as parameter, you cannot do it without dynamic SQL.